# Calling C++ with Xerces from COBOL: Trouble with Guardian and OSS path

Tags: c++, cobol, xerces-c

I am writing an cobol program that calls a c++ program. This c++ program does some XML validation using Xerces c++. When I write a standalone C++ programm, I get no errors. When I call the c++ programm from cobol, there occurs an error when calling the parse method of [SAXParser](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAXParser.html) because xerces cannot find the xml file. Inside the c++ program, I can open the file but xerces cannot.

Xerces thinks that the path to the xml is in OSS style `/G/vol/subvol/filename`, but it's in guardian style `vol.subvol.filename` This error occurs only when I'm using Xerces, not when using the c++ program.

My standalone c++ program that calls xerces works fine. Has anybody an idea why this error occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: Seems a little bit unclear: Where does the filename for the XML comes from? I assume it comes from COBOL (you've missed to specify which COBOL on what OS you use btw). If this is correct: How does the COBOL and C field definition looks like? How do you pass the COBOL field to C?

Comment: I am using cobol85 on a HP Nonstop (guardian os). The XML file is created by the c program, so the filename is in the right format. But xerces is still thinking that the program runs on the other hp nonstop os(oss, just like unix). There are several methods to tell the compiler (c89) and linker (eld) that I want to run the program and xerces on the guardian platform, just like the `GuardianTandemPlatformUtils.o` or the option `systype=guardian`: Btw my standalone c program is compiled and linked by the same makefile as the c program that is linked to my cobol program.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the `InputSource` class with base- and relative-path as shown [here](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classLocalFileInputSource.html#aa40f6d0d8010a45a678c53faf5f7e67c). After this I am calling the `parser.parse(&inputSource)` and get no error.